# initialise const struct with const pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, constants

I want to form a struct from const parameters passed to the function. As the parameters are const, i guess the struct has to be const too. However, it does not work with pointers.

The following code compiles (MinGW 4.9.2 32bit)

```
struct structType_t {
    int b;
};

void func1(const int b) {
    const structType_t s={b};  // invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

    // do something with s;
}
```

but with pointers it doesn't:

```
struct structType_t {
    int* b;
};

void func1(const int* b) {
    const structType_t s={b};  // invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

    // do something with s;
}
```

Why does the compiler try to cast away the const here?
So how can i use a const pointer to initialise a const structure?

Comment: structType has `int* b` not `const int* b`

Comment: `const int` and `int const` is the same type, `const int*` and `int* const` are different types.

Comment: Even if i change the type of b to const int * const its not compiling. The only solution i found, was a const_cast, which i guess is totaly safe here. But i'd like to know, why i need const_cast with pointers, but not with interger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you are creating a copy of an int. Copy of const int does not have to be const so it works.
In the second case you are creating copy of a pointer to const int and assigning it to a pointer to an int - this is not allowed and that's why it does not compile.

Answer (score 2):

If you change your struct to hold a `const int*` you can use it to store the `const int*` passed to the function, regardless of whether your `s` is `const` or not.

```
struct structType_t {
    const int* b;
};

void func1(const int* b) {
     const structType_t s={b};
     // or 
     structType_t s2={b};

    // do something with s or s2 ...
}
```

Comment: I can not change the struct to hold a const. 
However, declaring a struct as const is making all the members const, right?

Comment: Yes, it will make it hold a const pointer to an int (`int* const`) but not a pointer to a const int (`const int*`), which is what you want to store.